# Manipulate Arrays in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I tried to manipulate an array in an `NSMutableDictionary` directly:

```
[[myDictionary objectForKey: @"key"] addObject: object];
```

This doesn't work! I even tried type casting:

```
[(NSMutableArray*)[myDictionary objectForKey: @"key"] addObject: object];
```

This didn't work either!

The only way that worked was:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [myDictionary objectForKey: @"key"];
[array addObject: object];
[myDictionary setObject: array forKey: @"key"]
```

Is there a way to manipulate the array in the dictionary similar to the first code snippet; i.e. without having to create a new array, manipulating it and then saving it?

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't work"? Compiler errors? Crash? Exception? Wrong result?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work. Because all your variants are equal?

Comment: and you are sure that this is the exact code that you have problems with? Because the first try works perfectly.

Comment: After using the first method and then displaying the contents of the array the array is empty. If I use the third method it works fine i.e. the objects exist and are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't allocation the array within the NSMutable Dictionary i.e. before adding objects use the following code:

```
[myDictionary addObject: [[NSMutableArray alloc]init] forKey: @"key"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you loading the NSDictionary from a file or URL by any chance? From the API docs: "The objects contained by this dictionary are immutable, even if the dictionary is mutable."

Comment: No the dictionary is loaded at runtime

Comment: this doesn't tell us how you load it

Comment: I have an array of objects then I just use [myDictionary addObject:array forKey:@"key"];

Comment: This doesn't explain how the first method fails and the third succeeds. All the three are identical anyway, even if the `key` is not found in the dictionary.

Comment: The first two do not return errors they just don't work, the objects don't get added to the array